# WCF: Simple security by passing a password to every method

Tags: c#, wcf, security, passwords

Let there be a Windows service and a WCF service that need to exchange data on a regular basis.

Now let's assume that instead of [diving into the depths of WCF security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650862.aspx), the developer decides to simply add a `String password` parameter to every `OperationContract` signature (created randomly and supplied to both the Windows service and the WCF service via app.config/web.config) and activate HTTPS to ensure encryption.

It there something *inherently wrong* with this approach?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this approach at all. That is what most API's do with BASIC Auth, API Keys, or oAuth (not necessarily passwords, but still passing some sort of authentication parameter)

Comment: Yes, there is... You are re-inventing the wheel. You should use proven approaches / methods to solve problems rather than creating your own. Why? Because you are likely to make the same mistake as others in the past and not learn through their experiences. By this I mean the general idea of passing in a user/password is fine but the details on HOW need to be considered. I.e. headers, meta etc...

Comment: I think the problem with it is that it couples the business logic with the security. If you change it to add a username too then you have to add the extra username parameter to every method rather than just to a module. Also clients have to write custom authentication code, while if you use a standard approach then there are likely to be standard libraries which pass the credentials.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a simple way forward for small services where you're in control of server and client. However, I can think of two things which are inherently wrong with it. The first is that it violates the Single Responsibility Principle: the principle that classes should only have one reason to change. Your class will need to change for two reasons: firstly if the business logic of the service changes, and secondly if your authentication logic changes, say to add a username to the password credential or to make some methods available anonymously while continuing to require authentication on others.

The second is that while it may be easier not to use a standard method of authentication from the server side, it may make life more difficult for the clients, because they'll have to read your documentation rather than referring to a standard, and they won't be able to take advantage of any libraries which may have implemented much of the logic for them. Implementing a client for HTTP Basic authentication in .NET, for example, is really easy - you just supply the credentials as a property of the request and it does the handshake and the Base64 encoding for you.